# How to create a new List in Python, such that manipulations to the new list does not affect the old one?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, list-manipulation

In the below code, I copied the contents of  list  `a` to contents of list `prod`. When I change `prod` list values, `a` list values are also getting changed.I also tried using `prod=a[:].` 
I want the list `a` to be intact. Thanks in advance!l

```
a=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
b=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
prod=a.copy()
for i in range(3):
  sum=0
  for j in range(3):
    sum=0
    print("a= ",a[i][j])
    prod[i][j]=0
    print("a= ",a[i][j])
    for k in range(3):
      sum+=a[i][k]*b[k][j]
      print(a[i][k],b[k][j])
    prod[i][j]=sum  
    print("Sum=",sum,"A[i][k]=",a[i][k])
print(prod)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to `deepcopy()` it instead because it is nested lists..

```
from copy import deepcopy

a=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
b=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
prod= deepcopy(a)
for i in range(3):
  sum=0
  for j in range(3):
    sum=0
    print("a= ",a[i][j])
    prod[i][j]=0
    print("a= ",a[i][j])
    for k in range(3):
      sum+=a[i][k]*b[k][j]
      print(a[i][k],b[k][j])
    prod[i][j]=sum  
    print("Sum=",sum,"A[i][k]=",a[i][k])
print(prod)
```